# Image path stored in variable doesn't render properly in template

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

If I used `@/` in template, it works fine:

`<img src="@/assets/images/image.png">`

However if I use it in a variable, it doesn't: I just see it intact in the DOM (`<img src="@/...">`) which of course makes the image not render at all on the page.

Why?

```
<template>
  <section>
    <article
      v-for="article in articles"
    >
      <img :src="article.imageUrl" />
      ...
    </article>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [
        {
          imageUrl: "@/assets/images/AdobeStock_135975827_Preview.jpeg"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try with: `imageUrl: require("@/assets/images/AdobeStock_135975827_Preview.jpeg")` https://forum.vuejs.org/t/img-src-require-url-not-working/39704/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the webpack, `@` and `~` only work in templete or import/require in script.
So, if you want to define url in a variable, let's use absolute URL.